# Speeding up a SQL view by pre-filtering results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, sql-server-2016, sql-view

I have a view operating on a very large table.

```
CREATE VIEW [myView]
AS

-- first part
WITH A AS (
SELECT MAX(Id), ResultId, LocationId, TeamId
FROM VeryLargeTable
GROUP BY ResultId, LocationId, TeamId)    
--second part
SELECT A.Id, A.TeamId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResultId, LocationId) RN  
FROM A
WHERE RN = 1
GO
```

Now what I run operations such as

```
SELECT * from [MyView] 
WHERE TeamId = 5
```

This is very slow because it is essentially executing

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT MAX(Id), ResultId, LocationId, TeamId
FROM VeryLargeTable
GROUP BY ResultId, LocationId, TeamId)    
--second part
SELECT A.Id, A.TeamId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResultId, LocationId) RN  
FROM A
WHERE RN = 1 AND TeamId = 5
```

What I want to know is how to structure this view so it will know to filter for `TeamId = 5` in the first part so that, the following code, which is fast, executes

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT MAX(Id), ResultId, LocationId, TeamId
FROM VeryLargeTable
GROUP BY ResultId, LocationId, TeamId
WHERE TeamId = 5)    
--second part
SELECT A.Id, A.TeamId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResultId, LocationId) RN  
FROM A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Please post your actual code. View can't contain temporary table. Second - predicate pushdown should work

Comment: Ahh ok, I was doing it with CTEs currently- will convert

Comment: What indices do you have on VeryLargeTable?  And when you have a few free minutes, read up on "XY Problems" :)

Comment: @Lukasz Could be any combination of columns

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite your view as Inline TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.my_func(@TeamId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
WITH A AS (
  SELECT MAX(Id), ResultId, LocationId, TeamId
  FROM VeryLargeTable
  WHERE TeamId = @TeamId OR @TeamId IS NULL
  GROUP BY ResultId, LocationId, TeamId
)    
--second part
SELECT A.Id, A.TeamId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResultId, LocationId) RN  
FROM A
WHERE RN = 1 
);
```

And query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.my_fun(5)
WHERE ...
```